# convert list of tuples to list

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

This seems to be more problematic than I imagined so I need a little help here, please. 
Doing a sql extraction, it has given me an list of tuples, such as below:

```
print(queryresult)
Out[44]: 
[(100001, 'Test1'),
 (100003, 'Test2'),
 (100005, 'Test3')]
```

How do I remove all the brackets and parentheses so that it just displays the two rows. (it is important that the integers remain with the strings.
My desired output would be like this:

```
100001, 'Test1'
100003, 'Test2'
100005, 'Test3'
```

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
print([s.strip('[',']') for s in result])

[tuple(x.strip('()') for x in result) for result in a]
```

It seems that the fact that one of the rows is of integer type and the other of string type complicates things...

Eventually, I want to write these results to a textfile.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @khelwood Do you mean `map(repr, row)`? (since `map` requires an iterable)

Comment: @Wondercricket Yes I do. Well spotted.

Comment: Thnx for the quick response, but your solution throws an error at me.. TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, map found

Comment: `print('\n'.join(', '.join(map(repr, row)) for row in queryresult))`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I put the additional parenthesis at the end, not after row. That fixed it.

Comment: Does print(queryresult) print exactly how you show above? I'm confused by the "Out[44]:" bit. Where is that from?

Comment: I use Spyder and this is how the output is displayed on screen. I copied/ pasted it to here. What's confusing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in queryresult:
    print("%d, '%s'" %(i[0], i[1]))
```